# Monetize solitaire game

Tags: ios, monetization

I recently released my first game - solitaire for ios.

What the best way to monetize game?

Options I have in mind:

1. In-app purchase themes (cards, backgrounds etc...)
2. Ads subscription (remove ads)
3. Limited number of games which can be played in certain
   period of time with possibility to buy “life”.
4. Paid return (back) button.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A good question in itself, but not suitable to our site's Q&A format. We'd love to discuss it in chat though. Come by! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

Comment: I'm hoping this question can get a couple upvotes even though it's off topic so he can come chat with us.